# In VSCode, is there a command to navigate from a diff view to the local file

Tags: visual-studio-code, diff

Let's say I've clicked on a file in the Git changes view and it opened a diff.  I realize I can (usually) edit that file on the right side of the diff.

Is there a command that will open the right hand (local) file in it's own editor, as if I had clicked on it in the Explorer?

Answer (score 7):

The command is `git.openFile`. You can add a custom keybinding, for example to `f4`:

```json
    {
        "key": "f4",
        "command": "git.openFile",
        "when": "isInDiffEditor"
    }
```

Comment: Just want to say thank you so much for this. It is so mandatory but so difficult to find

Answer (score 3):

Do you consider the *Open File* icon to the right of the file name a command? I'm not familiar with any other way to do it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that icon in the Tab strip... for reference, that is not the general Open File command, but the git.openFile command.

Also, while I was waiting I also found a half answer in that using the Reveal Active File In SideBar command places the keyboard focus on the file in the Explorer and then you can hit Enter.

Comment: What's the difference between the general versus git open file command?

Comment: workbench.action.files.openFile (usually mapped to Ctrl + O) opens the Open File dialog so that you can select a file from your hard drive.  git.openFile navigates from a diff to the file (not in the diff mode)

Answer (score 1):

It appears what you want is the new command `workbench.action.compareEditor.openSide` currently in the Insiders' Build v1.74.

If the right-hand side of the diff has focus then triggering that command will close the diff and open the right-hand side in its editor.  And similarly if the left-hand side had focus.

Comment: I wonder if there are cases that this command handles and `git.openFile` doesn't 